# How many models can Alfresco Share Community 7.0 handle?

Tags: xml, model, share, alfresco, skip

I'm trying to write models to alfresco share 7.0 community edition, but after using the first model registered i can't save data from other models. I've got a parse error and looking at the logs at the docker container says it's skiping some model. I have seen the instructions about avoid spaces at the model's name and its types and different namespaces for each. None of these instructions were enough to figure out whats going on. Is it like it can handle just one model in community version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Alfresco CE there is no such limitation. You can define as many models as you want - as long as they are defined correctly ;-)

Did you try to enable

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.dictionary=debug
```

in your `log4j.properties`?

To focus on the document model only you can just use the [Dynamic deployment approach](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/5.2/develop/repo-ext-points/content-model/#dynamic-deployment-approach) by storing the model in the dictionary folder and using the "Model and Messages Console" to load and unload the model during runtime without the need to restart.